# regex expression to validate password

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression to validate passwords with the following requirements

Length : minimal 4 chars, maximum 39 chars
Allowed chars : a-z, A-Z, 0-9, minus, underscore, at-sign and dot
Additional : not-repeating and not-incremental like 'aaaa' or '1234' or 'abcd'

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9@.-_]{4,39}$
```

Comment: Non-incremental seems to make this a dealbreaker for regexes.

Comment: [Relevant XKCD](http://xkcd.com/936/)...

Comment: To do non-repeating (but no check on non-incremental), check [`^(?:([\w@.-])(?!\1)){4,39}$`](http://regex101.com/r/kB0gH7/1). Note: `\w = [a-zA-Z0-9_]` and `-` should go at the beginning or end of a character class (or be escaped) so the engine knows you aren't trying to do a range from `.` to `_` (RE: `[.-_]`).

Comment: What about people using "incremental" patterns on the keyboard, e.g. "qwerty" "jkl;" etc. Password restrictions are annoying and can end up reducing the security of the password.

Answer (score 0):

Sure this can be done in a verbose manner.
After all, its up to you to define what is sequential.
Just flesh out the rest of this regex:

```
 # ^(?:(a(?!b)|b(?!c)|c(?!d)|d(?!e)|1(?!2)|2(?!3)|3(?!4)|4(?!5)|[@._-])(?!\1)){4,39}$

 ^ 
 (?:
      (                     # (1 start)
           a
           (?! b )
        |  b 
           (?! c )
        |  c 
           (?! d )
        |  d 
           (?! e )
           # Add the rest of the alphabet here

        |  1 
           (?! 2 )
        |  2 
           (?! 3 )
        |  3 
           (?! 4 )
        |  4 
           (?! 5 )
           # Add the rest of the numbers here

        |  [@._-]  
           # Add any other sequential symbols here

      )                     # (1 end)
      (?! \1 )              # Non-repeating
 ){4,39}
 $
```